# Filter a variable to specific part / character | Auto set resolution from filtered text | Ubuntu, Bash

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu, xrandr

I am trying to make a script that sets the resolution to 1920x1080 at 60Hz as seen below...

The script should filter to get the specific parameters for xrandr as the output of both commands has some text that is not needed.

Then set the resolution to the primary display eg. HDMI1 or VGA1 to use the newly created mode.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script that sets resolution to 1920x1080 at 60Hz

CVTOUT=$(cvt 1920 1080 60)
# here insert a filter that removes the other output of cvt to begin
# with "1920x1080_60.00".. so xrandr is satisfied if the variable gets 
# passed as a parameter.

DISPLAYNAME=$(xrandr)
# here insert a filter that filters the entire output of the xrandr 
# command and gets only the display name, setting the corresponding 
# variable to use the newly filtered text. 

# Begin the part that actually sets the resolution via xrandr

# create new mode with the filtered variable
xrandr --newmode $CVTOUT

# add the mode with the filtered display name parameter from above
xrandr --verbose --addmode $DISPLAYNAME "1920x1080_60.00"

# set the display (represented by the variable) to use the newly added mode
xrandr --output $DISPLAYNAME --mode "1920x1080_60.00"
```

> P.S.
>
> > I know that setting it via a script on boot etc is not the correct way, you don't need to lecture me about best practices and how to do it in a configuration file...

> System: Ubuntu 20.04 with just the core system utils, gnome terminal, openbox, and xorg

Comment: What do you mean by `get display name command` ?

Comment: @Philippe a command that gets the primary display name, couldn't find one eg. HDMI1 or VGA1 etc.

Comment: If you run `xrandr` without any argument, it will display the current screen, and all available resolutions.  Ex. on my laptop, it shows line 1 `Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192`, line2 `eDP-1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm`

Comment: @Nic3500 yes but now parse the info so that it fits with the parameters needed for xrandr

Comment: Indeed, you have to parse, to extract the first word of the second like, which gives you the name of your primary display.